# How is a diffraction sheet made?

Tags: diffraction

[image]

This is Action Lab's explanation:

"The way these diffractive sheets are made is there’s not actually slits in it like the double slit experiment. There’s lines and grids of reflective surfaces that act like a hole or a slit in it. It’s reflecting the light and some is passing through."

The link to the video is here and he starts talking about it at 5:37

https://youtu.be/yhmCRliJ93w?t=337

However, I still don't really understand as I can't visually see it. I understand the double slit experiment which is all over Youtube, but not a lot talks about how these sheets are made. Can someone help clarify?

Comment: One obvious possibility is pressing from a master, like CDs and such can be mass produced. And CDs and DVDs can even act as reflection gratings, as used in all the cereal box spectroscopes on the web.

Answer (score 2):

At least some of these diffraction grating sheets [are](https://bartovation.com/product/other-lab-supplies/diffraction-grating-sheets/13500-lines/) holographic optical elements. Holograpic gratings are [formed by an interference-fringe field of two laser beams whose standing-wave pattern is exposed to a polished substrate coated with photoresist.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_grating)